# Rails cucumber assert tests cause undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I have a project with some cucumber testing. The tests used to execute with success and now any test that uses an assert object fail with error when I run
`rake cucumber` from the console

For example I have a cucumber test

```
Then (/^I should see the Pet Quiz page$/) do
    assert page.current_path == "/pet_quiz/index"
end
```

And am given the error

```
 Then I should see the Pet Quiz page    # features/step_definitions/pet_quiz_steps.rb:8
      undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
      ./features/step_definitions/pet_quiz_steps.rb:9:in `/^I should see the Pet Quiz page$/'
      features/pet_quiz.feature:10:in `I should see the Pet Quiz page'
```

Below is my Gemfile, I believe the source of the error may have come from one of the gems

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.7'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.4', '>= 5.2.4.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# For accessing environment variables in the app, for API keys
gem 'dotenv-rails'

# Use bootstrap sassc
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.4.1'
gem 'sassc-rails', '>= 2.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'

#geocoding gem
gem 'geocoder'

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
    # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  
  #Rspec for unit testing
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0.1'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'

end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  #use sqlite3 for testing
  gem 'sqlite3'
  
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  
  #Rspec for unit testing
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0.1'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.21' # for Heroku deployment
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]


gem 'webdrivers', '~> 4.0', require: false
```

Any idea what caused this error to happen?

Comment: The error seems to be caused by the 'rspec-rails' gem. When it is removed the cucumber tests work fine. How can I get rspec and cucumber to play nice together?

Answer (score 0):

Looks its some configuration issue, not `gem issue`.

- First of all, you don't need `rake`, you can run it by just executing `cucumber`
- why do you have `capybara` and `cucumber` in your Gemfile at the same time?
- Have you installed `rspec-rails` properly? Rspec tests are passing fine?
- I guess you don't need all of testing gems in `development` Gemfile group

Please don't rush and add gems 1 by 1, not all from the scratch - this will reduce error sources

Also, maybe helpful - easy setup guide from [semaphore team](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-a-bdd-stack-on-a-rails-5-application)